# Extensible First Person Shooter in C++?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I've recently become interested in the study of AI programming and how it relates to games. I'm interested to see what it's like to create AI for a first person shooter-type game with C++.

So, that leads me to my question. I would rather not spend my time writing a complete FPS just for the purpose of practicing AI design, so does anyone know of any existing projects/engines with completely functional games that I could simply extend (in C++) with AI somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask this at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to start with the Source or Unreal engines, and then use their bot APIs or scripting plugins to experiment with writing character code.

For example, there are lots of [bots](http://epodbot.bots-united.com/) for the FPS *CounterStrike*. [*Alien Swarm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Swarm) also shipped with the source code as part of its SDK, so you could start with the AIs there and modify them.

Answer (score 3):

You could download the source code for this:

http://sauerbraten.org/

And try to extend the `Single Player` mode, add new enemies with different AI or something.

Answer (score 0):

BZFlag ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BZFlag), [website](http://bzflag.org/)) is yet another such fps.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @rhalbersma:  The question was: "does anyone know of any existing projects/engines with completely functional games that I could simply extend (in C++) with AI somehow?"   How is this not an answer?

Comment: The review guidelines say that when giving links, an excerpt of that link should also be given (to avoid future bit rot of external sites). Sorry if I assigned the wrong edit category.

Comment: @rhalbersma: This is a list question, and it asks for project names.  What kind of summary do you imagine someone giving?

Comment: OK, you are right, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out, and thanks for editing anyway. I suppose nitpicking that a link to the engine's website itself (rather than Wikipedia) would add insult to injury? ;-)

Comment: @rhalbersma:  That sounds like a good idea.  Feel free to add the link.  (I would also keep the wikipedia link.)

Answer (score 0):

This wikipedia link has a list of different (free and open source) 3D engines.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend the Retribution Engine. It is open source and specifically designed for first person shooters.

Answer (score 0):

Crysis' Cryengine is the best by far of the FPS genre and severely needs someone to make Bots for it..I'm sure it's C++ and if you can then you will indeed go very far and be in great demand.. it's free

Either that or UDK - Unreal developer Kit - free - A structured OOP engine I believe (sorry I'm not a coder - only an artist and writer. :)

Good luck